# Why should I urlencode URLs passed via GET

Tags: php, html, url, get, urlencode

Suppose I do

```
http://site.com/something?url=http://lol.com/lol
```

are there any advantages (eg security etc) of doing

```
'http://site.com/something?url=' . urlencode('http://lol.com/lol');
```

instead of just passing in an unencoded version of the url in? Why should I urlencode something passed via GET instead of just passing in an uncoded version (though of course if the url param has & or ? or = in it then I should definitely encode it...but suppose they don't, why should I encode them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are characters which have special meaning in URLs. Those characters will have special meaning in the outer URL (instead of the inner URL where they belong) if you pass them without encoding.

For example, if you want to pass

```
http://example.com/foo?1=2&3=4
```

And you don't encode it, then you will get:

```
http://example.com/?url=http://example.com/foo?1=2&3=4
```

with

```
url is http://example.com/foo?1=2
3 is 4
```

> suppose they don't, why should I encode them

Because then you have to look at every URL you pass to decide if it needs encoding or not.

Always encoding is much simpler and less error prone then deciding on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

as long as i know the second sample is pretty good if you have the probalability to use unicode characters in your url.